# How can I assign values to a surface in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, boundary, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to build a 3D CFD pipe flow model using MATLAB, and I am hoping to assign values (boundary conditions) on the pipe wall. I've tried building a pipe using the `cylinder` function:

```
[X Y Z] = cylinder
```

but this generates me several points on the surface, which are not enough.

Aside, is there a better way to build a 3D [CFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) pipeflow model using MATLAB?

Comment: For more points, you can specify two more arguments in the `cylinder` function: `cylinder(r, n)`, where `r` is the profile curve and `n` is the number of equally-spaced points around its circumference. For example, `cylidner(1, 100)` creates a cylinder with unit radius and 100 points. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a struct to embed information in your CFD object.

```
% radius = 10
r = 10;
% number of radial points = 30
n = 30;
CFD_cyl = struct;
[CFD_cyl.X, CFD_cyl.Y, CFD_cyl.Z] = cylinder(r, n);
% Creates a value vector in the CFD_cyl struct that can relate to the cylinder X, Y, Z
CFD_cyl.value = CFD_cyl.X(:,:) + CFD_cyl.Y(:,:) + CFD_cyl.Z(:,:);
```

Change the value field accordingly for the useful relationship that you wish to express.